# Marque text not moving if texts are less in android

Tags: android, android-layout, textview, marquee

I am using below code, it's working fine for big statement, but not for small text like only "hello".

```
<TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:ellipsize="marquee"
            android:marqueeRepeatLimit="marquee_forever"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:scrollHorizontally="true"
            android:singleLine="true"
            android:text="this_bill_has_some_unipay_points_promotion"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call TextView.isSelected = true to start the text moving.

Edit: Working solution

```
<TextView
     android:id="@+id/textView"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"             
     android:layout_height="48dp"
     android:ellipsize="marquee"
     android:gravity="center_vertical"
     android:scrollHorizontally="true"
     android:singleLine="true"
     android:textColor="@android:color/white" />
```

Extension function

```
fun TextView.setMovingText(text: String) = this.post {
            val textWidth = this.paint.measureText(text)
            val spaceWidth = this.paint.measureText(" ")
            val requiredAdditionalSpace = ((this.width - textWidth) / spaceWidth).toInt()
            this.text = StringBuilder(text).apply {
                for (i in 0..requiredAdditionalSpace) {
                    append(" ")
                }
            }
            this.isSelected = true
        }
```

How to use

```
textView.setMovingText("Hey")
```

I just wanted to show a working solution. Also you can (should) modify for better performance and check for negative values.

Comment: i am using TextView.isSelected = true, and it's moving also. my query is something else, if text is very small like "hello" or "Amit"  then it is not moving. means if text length is less then textview width then its not moving otherwise moving. i want to make it scroll always with any text of any length.

Comment: Maybe you should check text length and then set textviews width to a smaller size.

Comment: my text view width is fix to device width i can't change that. even if change the width of view dynamically then in case of "hello" word. the view width will be very less. it will look like small floating icon. that is not required

Comment: Can you try adding space for remaining width as a workaround?

Comment: yeah that i can try, but every time my text will change dynamically from server. so how to get exact count of spaces. ?

Comment: Perfect solution!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of   ***android:layout_width="match_parent"*** you have to set layout width like (30dp 40dp) because The marquee is enabled when the characters are longer than the View's width.

Comment: is there any way , so that i can move character , even if character then is less then view width.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, As per marquee property if the text ware less then the width of the layout then it should not scroll.

If you still want to move it then you can do set manually/static width set of the view and the text will be moving, in layout .xml file you get the idea of width of the text view. still having issue let me know.

Comment: i tried, it's not working, i gave 200dp width and text "hello". but not moving.

Comment: you minimum text width ?

Comment: it can be 4-5 character word.

Comment: you have two choice 
1) set 30dp as width as your Textview and set appropriate with your UI
2) concrete some white space character ("\t") before and after at time of set text in your Textview